# Word for "delegating" with negative connotation

Tags: word-choice

I am writing a complaint letter: "...she gets others to do her job and she claims the credit..."

The only word I know for "getting others to do her job" is "delegating", but it sounds too positive. What is the correct word to imply that she is just making use of people to her advantage?

Comment: Is she a supervisor or manager claiming credit for the work of her direct reports, or does she get her peers to pick up her slack?

Comment: In the sense of the stated complaint, "shirking" is probably the best of the options mentioned so far.

Comment: @JasonM she makes friends with junior staff from other departments and asks them to do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original phrase, or a variant like “she gets others to do her work, then claims credit herself”, seems good enough already, but if you wish to add more-negative connotations, consider the verbs  *inveigle* and  *slough* (or *sluff*), as in:

> She inveigles others to do her work...
>   She sloughs her work onto others...

From [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inveigle), *inveigle* means “to convert, convince or win over with flattery or wiles”.  Also from [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slough#Verb), *slough* has senses including “To shed” and “To slide off”. *[Shift](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shift#Verb)* also works.

Comment: Oh! inveigles could not be more apt for my case! learnt something new today.

Answer (score 2):

When I give a distasteful or boring task to one of my junior staff, I'll outright tell them I'm "***offloading***" (or *unloading*) it on them.

Answer (score 2):

You could say: "to fob (a task) off onto someone"

Answer (score 1):

She is *shirking* responsibility for her work. All that means is that she evades tasks that she should carry out, it doesn't say anything about claiming credit, or how she gets others to do her work.

Answer (score 0):

How about "passing the buck?"

Admittedly, it is a phrase and not a word, but it has a nice punchy sound to it.

Answer (score -2):

How about micro-managing?

Or if you want to be more flowery, he or she is "putting the weight on everyone else's shoulders"

Comment: Pretty much the opposite.